# Applying a css style file across multiple iframes

Tags: javascript, css, iframe

I have a problem that is perplexing me and I can not find a solution. I have a page with four iframes on it. On load a javascript function is run by:

```
<body onLoad="dm_on();">
```

The javascript function is:

```
function dm_on()
{
    var iframes  = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe');

    for (var i = 0, len = iframes.length, doc; i < len; ++i) 
    {
        doc = iframes[i].contentDocument || iframes[i].contentWindow.document;

        doc.open();
        doc.write(ta_text[i]);
        doc.close();

        doc.designMode = 'On';
    }

    var cssLink1  = document.createElement("link");
    cssLink1.href = "style.css"; 
    cssLink1.rel  = "stylesheet"; 
    cssLink1.type = "text/css";

    var cssLink2  = document.createElement("link");
    cssLink2.href = "style.css"; 
    cssLink2.rel  = "stylesheet"; 
    cssLink2.type = "text/css";

    var cssLink3  = document.createElement("link");
    cssLink3.href = "style.css"; 
    cssLink3.rel  = "stylesheet"; 
    cssLink3.type = "text/css";

    var cssLink4  = document.createElement("link");
    cssLink4.href = "style.css"; 
    cssLink4.rel  = "stylesheet"; 
    cssLink4.type = "text/css";

    rtf1.document.head.appendChild(cssLink1);
    rtf2.document.head.appendChild(cssLink2);
    rtf3.document.head.appendChild(cssLink3);
    rtf4.document.head.appendChild(cssLink4);
}
```

Turning design mode on and writing to each iframe works. I would have thought the following would work but it does not:

```
function dm_on()
{
    var iframes  = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe');
    
    var cssLink  = document.createElement("link");
    cssLink.href = "style.css"; 
    cssLink.rel  = "stylesheet"; 
    cssLink.type = "text/css";

    for (var i = 0, len = iframes.length, doc; i < len; ++i) 
    {
        doc = iframes[i].contentDocument || iframes[i].contentWindow.document;

        doc.head.appendChild(cssLink);
        doc.open();
        doc.write(ta_text[i]);
        doc.close();

        doc.designMode = 'On';
    }
}
```

What perplexes me even more is that the following does not work either.

```
function dm_on()
{
    var iframes  = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe');

    for (var i = 0, len = iframes.length, doc; i < len; ++i) 
    {
        doc = iframes[i].contentDocument || iframes[i].contentWindow.document;

        doc.open();
        doc.write(ta_text[i]);
        doc.close();

        doc.designMode = 'On';
    }

    var cssLink  = document.createElement("link");
    cssLink.href = "style.css"; 
    cssLink.rel  = "stylesheet"; 
    cssLink.type = "text/css";

    rtf1.document.head.appendChild(cssLink);
    rtf2.document.head.appendChild(cssLink);
    rtf3.document.head.appendChild(cssLink);
    rtf4.document.head.appendChild(cssLink);
}
```

rtf1, rtf2, rtf3, rtf4 are the iframes by name. The first code snippet posted gives each iframe a style but I need to apply the style in a loop or walk fashion as I don't know how many iframes will be on a page that includes this js file. Any help or push in the right direction will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: are they on the same domain name?

Comment: It looks as though you are trying to append the same element to four different places. I don’t see how that would work Where does it get appended to in say your final example.

Comment: @Lime They are on the same domain. 

<iframe name="rtf1" id="rtf1" style="border:#000000 1px solid; width:850px; height:100px;"></iframe>

Just on a php page with the above function included from a js file in the same directory.

Comment: @AHaworth are you saying I can not apply the element csslink to four different iframe heads? That would explain why using four different csslinks works and why the for loop does not work. Is there any chance you can explain why it does not work or maybe push me in the direction of a work around? If createElement creates an object that can only be used once like id is there a function that I can use for many like class?

Comment: I don’t entirely understand what you are doing, in particular I don’t know what ta_text is, but I would not expect an element to be usable in several places. Try creating a new one for each need inside the loop.